# Determinant of a matrix minus its transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix and $A^t$ be its transpose.

I know how to show $\mathrm{det}(A-A^t)=(-1)^n\mathrm{det}(A^t-A)$.

I would like to know how to show $\mathrm{det}(A-A^t)=(-1)^{\mathrm{rank} A}\mathrm{det}(A^t-A)$.

The strategy I took is as follows. If I can find matrices $U$ and $V$ such that $UAV$ and $UA^tV$ are in Row echelon form, then I can prove it but I also don't know how to construct these.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm thinking of a $2\times 2$ matrix $A$ of rank one, so according to what you say you know how to show, $det(A-A^t)$ is $det(A^t-A)$.  But in my example det$(A-A^t)$ is nonzero, which contradicts what you say you want to know how to show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to prove is not true. Take

$$A = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 3 \\ 2 & 6 \end{array}\right)$$

for which $\operatorname{rank}A=1$ and $\det(A-A^t)=\det(A^t-A)=1$,

because

$$A^t = \left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 6 \end{matrix}\right)$$
$$A^t-A = \left(\begin{matrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{matrix}\right)$$ .